# Using Qt Creator to develop an Apache2 module

Tags: qt, apache2, qt-creator

I'm developing an Apache2 module as a subproject of a larger project. The source file is (for example) module_example.c. Apache2 modules are compiled with [apxs2](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/programs/apxs.html), thus:

```
% apxs2 -c module_example.c
```

I've successfully added rules (patterned on how ODB works) to my Qt Creator .pro file to find and use apxs2, like this:

```
APXS_FLAGS =
APXS_FILES += module_example.c

for(dir, APXS_FILES) {
  APXS_PWD_FILES += $$PWD/$${dir}
}

apxs.name = apxs2 -c ${QMAKE_FILE_IN}
apxs.input = APXS_PWD_FILES
apxs.output = ${QMAKE_FILE_BASE}.so
apxs.commands = apxs2 $$APXS_FLAGS -c ${QMAKE_FILE_IN}
apxs.depends = $$APXS_PWD_FILES
apxs.clean = module_${QMAKE_FILE_BASE}.so
QMAKE_EXTRA_COMPILERS += apxs
```

QtCreator correctly compiles the module using apxs2 (although it leaves the binaries in the source directory instead of the build directory, which isn't ideal), but then *also* tries to compile it with GCC (which fails). How do I tell Qt Creator to use my "extra compiler" *instead* of the normal one? Changing the extension to something else (module_example.apxs, for example) doesn't appear to be an option, because apxs2 has no option to specify the extension of C source files. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not Qt Creator that does it, but qmake. You need to remove `module_example.c` from `SOURCES`. The problem is in the part of the .pro file you're not showing.

If you wish to easily access the file from Qt Creator, add it to `OTHER_FILES`. It will be shown in the project structure in the IDE, but won't be compiled by default.

Also, it's up to you to tell apxs to output to the build path. You need `${OUT_PWD}`.